# How to sort list objects in Python similar struct in C

Tags: python

I'm a newbie . I have a problem .

That problem is how to sort a list objects in Python similar struct in C

Example: I have code:

```
class struct():

    def __init__(self,first=0,second=0):
        self.f=first
        self.s=second

for i in range(1,n+1):
     a[i]=struct()
     a[i].f,a[i].s=map(int,input().split())


a.sort(key=???)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(a[i].f," ",a[i].s)
```

and the test :

```
4 3
7 4
15 10
2 2
1 5
```

I want to sort the list a [i] .f in ascending order and if there are more a [i] .f , I want to sort the a [i] .s in descending order.

Please tell me the solution. Thank u for reading

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, together with a description about your problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `functools` library, `total_ordering` class. Apply that as a decorator to your class and define the logic for which of two objects sorts higher / lower.